# Filtering results from an AngularFire2 realtime database query

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to filter an observable list returned from an AngularFire2 realtime database query, but the filter does not seem to apply and I get the whole list returned.

I have not been able to find much information online as it seems to be either relating to older versions before .pipe is used or to the newer firestore database.

```
getPosts(limit) {
    return this.db.list('/reasons', ref => ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(limit)).snapshotChanges().pipe( map( (data: any[] ) => {
      return data.map( post => {
        const $key = post.payload.key;
        const item = { $key, ...post.payload.val() };
        return item;
      })
      .filter(post => post.flag !== true || post.privacy !== true )
    }))
  }
```

Update:

I have got the filtering to work, but I'm not sure its the correct way to do it with rxjs 6.

Rather than just posting it as an answer I was hoping someone could check the structure as I'm not confident it should really be the accepted answer. It is obviously not following the structure suggested below of pipe ( map(), map(), filter() )

```
getPosts(limit) {
    return this.db.list('/reasons', ref => ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(limit)).snapshotChanges().pipe( 
      map( (data: any[] ) => {
        return data.map( data => {
          const $key = data.payload.key;
          const item = { $key, ...data.payload.val() };
          return item;
        }).filter(data => data.flag !== true).filter(data => data.privacy !== true)
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Dont do map().filter() its pipe ( map(), map(), filter() )

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more please? I have tried adjusting it but its wrong because it doesn't recognise filter anymore

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://indepth.dev/reading-the-rxjs-6-sources-map-and-pipe/

Comment: Thanks, that does help, but I'm still very unfamiliar with it and can't seem to get it to work. I have tried a few combinations but I get property flag does not exist on type unknown.